# How do i put texture from images?

Tags: texturing, materials, normal-map, displacement, bump

I have downloaded texture and it contains diffuse,normal,height images/maps.How to use them in blender to get bumpy/3d texture?

Answer (score 0):

The typical node arrangement looks like this. Remember to choose non-color for your metallic, roughness, normal, and displacement images. Also, remember all meshes must be UV unwrapped in order to display the materials properly.

[image]